# maven install error in eclipse juno

Tags: maven, eclipse-juno

While I am tring to install maven in eclipse juno I got this error.
error details:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: 
     compile)
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
     Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: The repository system is offline but the 
     artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 is not available in the local repository.
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, 
     phase: test-compile)
```

please help me if knows proper answer.

thanks

Comment: First i would check `The repository system is offline but the..` and try to build on command line...without any issue afterwards i would go into the IDE.

Comment: Check if inside Configuration of Eclipse Juno, Maven is in offline mode, if so, put it in online mode...

Answer (score 3):

If you're behind proxy be sure to define it in maven's `settings.xml`. I'm guessing you are using external maven installation so you can find this file in `MAVEN_HOME/conf`. Inside this file search for the `<proxies> </proxies>` tag and see the example between these tags of how can you set your proxy. 
Also be sure to choose external maven installation in Eclipse (`Preferences > Maven > Installations`). The last step is to configure the User Settings (`Preferences > Maven > User Setting`) to point to the `settings.xml` (Global and User). Run Update Project and the error should disappear.

Note that if you move to network without proxy, you should comment out the defined proxy in `settings.xml` or set the `<active>false</active>` tag in the `<proxy>` tag.

Comment: Wow... I've been making work-arounds on this issue for a good half year now, but I was starting a new project at work, and wanted to make the set-up correctly this time. I was just missing the pointer to user settings in Eclipse, that pointed to the Global settings. Thanks!